# Submitting form results that there is no error to another page

Tags: php

i want to know how to send value form my_name in index.php below to result.php.

below is the php code to check for errors after the input form.
and how to send form results that there is no error to result.php

here is index.php

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["_submit_check"]) {
    if ($form_errors = validate_form()) {
    show_form($form_errors);
    } else {
process_form();
}
} else {
show_form();
}

function process_form() {
//if doesnt makes error
//i want to send result "my_name" to result.php
header('Location: result.php');
}

function show_form($errors = '') {
    if ($errors) {
    print implode('</li><li><br>', $errors);
    print '</li></ul>';
}
print<<<_HTML_
<form method="POST" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
Your name: <input type="text" name="my_name">$errors[0];
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="hidden" name="_submit_check" value="1">
</form>
_HTML_;
}

function validate_form() {
    $errors = array();
    if (strlen($_POST['my_name']) < 3) {
    $errors[] = "Your name must be at least 3 letters long.";
    }
    return $errors;
}

?>
```

here is result.php

```
<?php
//prints result form from index.php
?>
```

Comment: `result.php` is completely useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with [HTTP GET variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
header('Location: result.php?name='.$_POST['my_name']);
```

in result.php

you can see the value

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: thank you. it works.
but, what if i have 2 fields. (my_name and my_addr)
and post to result.php

Comment: you can add more parameters separated with '&' like : header('Location: result.php?name='.$_POST['my_name'].'&address='.$_POST['my_address']);

Answer (score 1):

PHP session variables hold information among pages.

Please try this.

At index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  // set post date into session variable
  $_SESSION['my_name'] = $_POST['my_name'];
  $_SESSION['my_number'] = $_POST['my_number'];

?>
```

And at result.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  // get date from session variable
  $my_name = $_SESSION['my_name'];
  $my_number= $_SESSION['my_number'];
  echo $my_name;
  echo $my_number;
?>
```